# Angularjs onselect from dropdown

Tags: angularjs

I am using material angularjs

```
 <md-autocomplete   class="col-sm-10 " style="margin-left: 50px;"
                                 md-selected-item="ctrl.selectedItem"  
                                 md-search-text-change="ctrl.searchTextChange(ctrl.searchText)" 
                                 md-search-text="ctrl.searchText" 
                                 md-selected-item-change="ctrl.selectedItemChange(item)" 
                                 md-items="item in ctrl.universities | filter: ctrl.searchText" 
                                 md-item-text="item.name" 
                                 md-min-length="3" 
                                 placeholder="Search for College">
                    <md-item-template>
                        <span md-highlight-text="ctrl.searchText" md-highlight-flags="^i">{{item.name}}</span>
                    </md-item-template>
```

I know that ctrl.selectedItem relflects the item that I have selected from the dropdown but how can i make it so that when ctrl.selectdItem is not null make a http request in the controller??

Should i use $watch and use that on the variable to see if it changes? is there any other way to do this?

Comment: "when ctrl.selectdItem is not null make controller". Explain please.

Comment: @Arg0n editted the question sorry

Comment: You seem to have a function for `md-selected-item-changed`. Why not check for null in that and make the request? $watch works too btw.

Comment: if you use `md-selected-item-change` you don't ever need to `$watch` anything. Use the event handler (`ctrl.selectedItemChange` to check the value being null - if not, just use `$http` or `$resource` as always).